# How can I create a formula in Google Spreadsheets that uses a date format

Tags: google-sheets

How do I subtract days from a cell that has dates?

For example, what's a formula that will take 3/2/2011 and return this value 2/28/2011?

Is this possible in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it similar to Excel. Simply subtract the number of days from the cell.

For example: If you have in cell A1 3/2/2011 you can get 2/28/2011 in a cell by entering the formula `=A1-3`